# I'm scraping Yellow Pages with rvest and get a 403 Forbidden message when I run submit_form()

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape Yellow Pages with the help of `rvest`, but keep running into the 403 Forbidden error.
Here's the full code:

```
query = "daycare" 
loc = "yonkers, ny" 
session <- html_session("https://www.yellowpages.com/") 
form <- html_form(session)[[1]] 
form <- set_values(form, search_terms = query, geo_location_terms = loc) 
submitted_form <- submit_form(session, form)
```

I get the following message when I run it:

```
Submitting with '<unnamed>'
Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

The html form shows  as . Here's the full text:

```
<form> 'search-form' (GET /search)
  <input text> 'search_terms': 
  <input text> 'geo_location_terms': Richmond, VA
  <button submit> '<unnamed>
```

It's my understanding that the code is right, but the server isn 't giving me permission to perform the action. I've read that I could submit the request with some changes, but as someone who just started doing this kind of work, I'm not 100% sure.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't even access the website.

Comment: Some web pages use code to prevent scraping. Sounds like that's probably the case here.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! There are plenty services that scrape Yellow Pages, but I guess they must have some kind of license to do that.

Comment: I was getting 403 errors from yellowpages.com just using a browser until I turned off my VPN.